# Why wont the code print in Unitys console?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;   
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}
```

the stuff at the top is just stuff unity adds i am just adding this because my post has too much code apparently

```
void Update()
{
```

*This tells it to print hi in the console*

```
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) ;
    {
        Debug.Log("hi.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well is this attached to any object in your scene...? And remove the `;` behind the `if` otherwise it will print always ... Besides that I see no reason why it should not print except as already said it is not attached to a `GameObject` in your scene or that object is inactive or that component is disabled .. in which case this would be the expected behavior ...

Answer (score 2):

hmm, may be your problem is in your code, just clear the ; element

```
void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) 
    {
        Debug.Log("hi.");
    }
}
```

The compiler will show you a red error and also in unity editor.
If you have done my instruction but still can not do it, create a gameobject in the hierarchy and drag the script you have written to the gameobject